# how to convert a kivy app using scipy to android apk

Tags: python, android, scipy, kivy, buildozer

I tried to use buildozer to convert my kivy app that use packages like scipy to an android apk but it keep giving me errors. does someone know how to fix that or another option without using buildozer?